# TomTom traffic vector layer integration in ArcGIS SDK JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, style, maps, traffic, tomtom-api

I'm facing issues displaying results from the TomTom API in my ArcGIS JavaScript application. Despite configuring a Vector Tile Layer with TomTom traffic data, the results are not showing up on the map. I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the problem.

Code Snippet:

JavaScript this does not show anything on the map but it makes requests for the traffic data and

```
returns the data as .pbf file

 let vectorTileLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
    title: 'TomTom Traffic',
    style: {
      version: 8,
      sources: {
        tomtom: {
          type: 'vector',
          tileCompression: "gzip",
          tiles: ["https://c.api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/absolute/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key=hCsMmqZyJdl2R0HmgbL02FmpQVGmAMnT"],
          minzoom: 0,
          maxzoom: 22,
        },
      },
      layers: [
        {
          id: 'Traffic flow',
          type: 'fill',
          source: 'tomtom',
          'source-layer': 'public',
          paint: {
            'fill-color': 'red',
            'fill-opacity': 0.2,
            'fill-outline-color': 'blue',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

this works but it is an image tiles

```
 let tileLayer = new WebTileLayer({
    title: 'TomTom Traffic',
    urlTemplate: "https://c.api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/relative/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=hCsMmqZyJdl2R0HmgbL02FmpQVGmAMnT&thickness=8&tileSize=512",
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 22,
  });
```

Issue Details:

I have set up a Vector Tile Layer with TomTom traffic data using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. The TomTom API URL and parameters have been configured correctly. There are no console errors or warnings, but the results are not visible on the map. Additional Information:

How do I integrate TomTom API results with the ArcGIS JavaScript API?

I have verified the TomTom API key and ensured that it is valid. Other layers, such as WebTileLayer, are displaying correctly. I'm using version 4.21 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason while nothing is displayed with the above style is that `source-layer` attribute in layer specification is not set to the actual vector tile layer name. It doesn't help if `id` is set to the layer name, it can be anything, `source-layer` has to be set: `'source-layer': 'Traffic flow'`.

So this style

```
{
  version: 8,
  sources: {
    tomtom: {
      type: 'vector',
      tileCompression: "gzip",
      tiles: ["https://c.api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/absolute/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key=hCsMmqZyJdl2R0HmgbL02FmpQVGmAMnT"],
      minzoom: 0,
      maxzoom: 22,
    },
  },
  layers: [
    {
      id: 'Traffic',
      type: 'fill',
      source: 'tomtom',
      'source-layer': 'Traffic flow',
      paint: {
        'fill-color': 'red',
        'fill-opacity': 0.2,
        'fill-outline-color': 'blue',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

gives this image:

[image]

Obviously not OK, since style is of type `fill`, but traffic deals with lines, so layer style type should be `line`.

So this style

```
{
  version: 8,
  sources: {
    tomtom: {
      type: 'vector',
      tileCompression: "gzip",
      tiles: ["https://c.api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/absolute/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key=hCsMmqZyJdl2R0HmgbL02FmpQVGmAMnT"],
      minzoom: 0,
      maxzoom: 22,
    },
  },
  layers: [
    {
      id: 'Traffic',
      type: 'line',
      source: 'tomtom',
      'source-layer': 'Traffic flow',
      paint: {
        'line-color': 'blue'
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

gives much more acceptable image:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much